# C++: Write BMP image format error on WINDOWS

Tags: c++, windows, image, bitmap, bitmapimage

I have the most strange problem here... I'm using the same code(copy-paste) from Linux in Windows to **READ** and **WRITE** and **BMP** image. And from some reason in **Linux** every thing works **perfectly fine**, but when I'm coming to **Windows 10** from some I can't open that images and I've receive an error message how said something like this:

> "It looks like we don't support this file format."

Do you have any idea what should I do? I will put the code below.

**EDIT:**

I've solved the padding problem and now it's write the images but they are completely **white**, any idea why? I've update the code also.

```
struct BMP {
    int width;
    int height;
    unsigned char header[54];
    unsigned char *pixels;
    int size;
    int row_padded;
};

void writeBMP(string filename, BMP image) {
    string fileName = "Output Files\\" + filename;
    FILE *out = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "wb");
    fwrite(image.header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, out);

    unsigned char tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < image.height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.width * 3; j += 3) {
            // Convert (B, G, R) to (R, G, B)
            tmp = image.pixels[j];
            image.pixels[j] = image.pixels[j + 2];
            image.pixels[j + 2] = tmp;
        }
        fwrite(image.pixels, sizeof(unsigned char), image.row_padded, out);
    }
    fclose(out);
}

BMP readBMP(string filename) {
    BMP image;
    string fileName = "Input Files\\" + filename;
    FILE *f = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "rb");

    if (f == NULL)
        throw "Argument Exception";

    fread(image.header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f); // read the 54-byte header

    // extract image height and width from header
    image.width = *(int *) &image.header[18];
    image.height = *(int *) &image.header[22];

    image.row_padded = (image.width * 3 + 3) & (~3);
    image.pixels = new unsigned char[image.row_padded];
    unsigned char tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < image.height; i++) {
        fread(image.pixels, sizeof(unsigned char), image.row_padded, f);
        for (int j = 0; j < image.width * 3; j += 3) {
            // Convert (B, G, R) to (R, G, B)
            tmp = image.pixels[j];
            image.pixels[j] = image.pixels[j + 2];
            image.pixels[j + 2] = tmp;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return image;

}
```

In my point of view this code should be cross-platform... But it's not... why?

Thanks for help

Comment: You can use a compare tool in windows like windiff which comes with Visual Studio to compare the two files.Or use the debugger to make sure same image header data is written.

Comment: To compare what? It's exactly the same code...

Comment: I've check this code few time and it's exactly the same...

Comment: @Mircea To compare the BMP files, not the code.

Comment: @Mircea I think he means header data in the file.

Comment: It's the same image, in exactly the same folder...

Comment: Write a small 4x4 pixel BMP file on windows, from MS Paint. Now, write a small 4x4 pixel BMP file with your code. Compare the two files, byte by byte.

Comment: You are missing the padding involved in the BMP format.

Comment: @mascoj Thx for that observation, I've solved this and now I can write images but they are completely **whait**. I've update my question, can you check again please?

Comment: There's insufficient information here to debug the problem.  The BMP format is complicated and there are many, many ways to get it wrong.  The code sample doesn't show us anything about how the header is filled out, how the color table (if any) is written.  We don't know the bit depth (other than some of the code assumes 24-bit), the BITMAPINFOHEADER version.

Comment: I think your latest code edit is missing a `fwrite`, that's why it's all white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check the header**

The [header](http://www.fastgraph.com/help/bmp_header_format.html) must start with the following two [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) bytes: `0x42 0x4D`.  If it's something different a third party application will think that this file doesn't contain a bmp picture despite the .bmp file extension.

The size and the way pixels are stored is also a little bit [more complex than what you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34232350/3723423):  you assume that the number of bits per pixels is 24 and no no compression is used.  This is not guaranteed.  If it's not the case, you might read more data than available, and corrupt the file when writing it back.

Furthermore, the size of the header depends also on the [BMP version](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm) you are using, which [you can detect using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38546213/3723423) the 4 byte integer at offset 14.

**Improve your code**

When you load a file, check the signature, the bmp version, the number of bits per pixel and the compression.  For debugging purpose, consider dumping the header to check it manually:

```
for (int i=0; i<54; i++) 
    cout << hex << image.header[i] << " ";` 
cout <<endl;
```

Furthermore, when you `fread()` check that the number of bytes read correspond to the size you wanted to read, so to be sure that you're not working with uninitialized buffer data.

***Edit:***

Having checked the dump, it appears that the format is as expected. But verifying the padded size in the header with the padded size that you have calculated it appears that the error is here:

```
image.row_padded = (image.width * 3 + 3) & (~3);     // ok size of a single row rounded up to multiple of 4
image.pixels = new unsigned char[image.row_padded];  // oops !  A little short ?
```

In fact you read row by row, but you only keep the last one in memory !  This is different of your first version, where you did read the full pixels of the picture.

Similarly, you write the last row repeated height time.

Reconsider your padding, working with the total padded size.

```
image.row_padded = (image.width * 3 + 3) & (~3);     // ok size of a single row rounded up to multiple of 4
image.size_padded = image.row_padded * image.height;  // padded full size
image.pixels = new unsigned char[image.size_padded];  // yeah ! 
if (fread(image.pixels, sizeof(unsigned char), image.size_padded, f) !=  image.size_padded) {
    cout << "Error: all bytes couldn't be read"<<endl; 
}
else { 
    ... // process the pixels as expected
}
...
```

Comment: I've solve a part of my problem, I edit my question, you can check it again please?

Comment: well... the input image is ok, I can open it and look at it. My problem is just the output image. I've already check the header multiples times and it's perfect, or I couldn't see the difference. I've check even with `for (int i=0; i<54; i++) cout << hex << image.header[i] << " ";` and it's the same... Now if I have right, in this moment my problem is not header, it the pixels array. From some reason I've lose all the pixels I think in some way... Or I don't write it correctly. That I think it's my problem in this moment.

Comment: @Mircea could you please show me the result of the dump ?

Comment: Sure, the image of result it's here [here](http://imgur.com/OEPS5C0) I can't copy-paste the result like text here because are to many characters